# Is it possible to create a location element in web.config programmatically (using ConfigurationLocation for example)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-config

I can access and modify the contents of a <location> tag in web.config, starting from:

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(virtualFolderPath); 
ConfigurationLocationCollection locations = config.Locations;
```

then for each location:

```
Configuration thisConfig = location.OpenConfiguration();
```

However, I cannot see any way to add a new <location>, is that possible?

Comment: I have been able to work around this using XmlDocument to read the Web.config, add the relevant XMlElements and save the file.  Just seems a bit messy; especially when compared to existing options for other tags (AuthorizationSection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web.config is a legal XML document. So, other considerations aside, there is nothing to stop you from loading it and using either XMLDocumment / XPath or XDocument methods to modify and save the file.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing (other considerations aside as Peter says!)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to you to not do this programmatically, because whenever you are trying to `add/edit` values in the web.config, your application restarts and all users session will be terminated.
check this article for Details [Common reasons for the session loss issue in ASP.NET applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/akshayns/archive/2008/09/29/common-reasons-for-the-session-loss-issue-in-asp-net-applications.aspx)

Comment: I'm aware of that thanks, but still need this feature for an admin tool.

Comment: PS: It is possible to update other tags (eg using AuthorizationSection), just can't find a way to add a new location.

Answer (score 1):

A [`ConfigurationLocationCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationlocationcollection.aspx) is derived from a [`System.Collections. ReadOnlyCollectionBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.readonlycollectionbase.aspx) which is read-only. So using the configuration API's as they are just now this is not possible.